# When I separate the javascript and html files, only the age is displayed

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src = "A1P1Q1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="firstname"></p>
<p id="details"></p>

<script>
    variable();    
</script>
```

javascript code

```
  function variable(){
     age = 24;
    var fname = "sachin";
    lname = "hunur";
    details = [age, fname, lname];

    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "the age is" +" " +age;
    document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = "first name is" +
    " " + fname;
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = "The user details are" + 
    "age : " + details[0] + "first name : " + details[1] + " last name : "
    + details[2];
    return;
}
```

> Blockquote:The output shown is only :
>   the age is 24.

How do I get the first name and details printed?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: It sounds like it's getting an error after it shows the first output.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9ndt0gLt/

Comment: Works for me too. Does your actual code close off the `body` and `html` tags? Can you confirm that the file A1P1Q1.js contains the script posted above? What messages do you see in your console?

Comment: your code is working

Answer (score -2):

Correct you js code like below :

```
function variable() {
    var age = 24,
        fname = "sachin",
        lname = "hunur",
        details = new Array(
            age,
            fname,
            lname
        );

    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "the age is" + " " + age;
    document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = "first name is" +
        " " + fname;
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = "The user details are" +
        "age : " + details[0] + "first name : " + details[1] + " last name : "
         + details[2];
    return;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's different in your solution and why it works?